# VBS with space in file path 3

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBS but the path to a file has a space as below, I have tried putting it inbetween "" but it gives an error, please help.

```
Set Objshell=wscript.Createobject("Wscript.Shell")
Objshell.Run "Telnet"
wscript.sleep 100
Strday= left(date,2)
Strmonth = right(left(date,5),2)
StrYear = Right(date,4)
StrHr = Left(Time,2)
StrMin = Right(Left(time,5),2)
StrSec = Right(Time,2)
StrDate=Stryear & StrMonth & StrDay &"_"& StrHr & StrMin & StrSec
Wscript.sleep 1000
Objshell.sendkeys "set Logfile ""L:\09 Phones\Switch_Logs\""" & StrDate & ".txt"
Objshell.sendkeys "~"
Wscript.sleep 1000
```

Its the

```
Objshell.sendkeys "set Logfile ""L:\09 Phones\Switch_Logs\""" & StrDate & ".txt"
```

bit that im having the problem with.

Comment: try to wrap the path with ' instead of "

Comment: Like, Objshell.sendkeys "set Logfile "'L:\09 Phones\Switch_Logs\'"" & StrDate & ".txt"  ?

Comment: Objshell.sendkeys "set Logfile 'L:\09 Phones\Switch_Logs\" & StrDate & ".txt'"

Comment: the final output shold be set logfile 'l:\09 Phones\switch_logs\date.txt' you can try outputing it to the console and see where you are getting it wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
clear text      :  set Logfile  "L:\09 Phones\Switch_Logs\xxxxxxxxxxxx.txt"
double quotes   :  set Logfile ""L:\09 Phones\Switch_Logs\xxxxxxxxxxxx.txt""
quote as string : "set Logfile ""L:\09 Phones\Switch_Logs\xxxxxxxxxxxx.txt"""
cut for variable: "set Logfile ""L:\09 Phones\Switch_Logs\"           ".txt"""
concatenate     : "set Logfile ""L:\09 Phones\Switch_Logs\"& StrDate &".txt"""
```

Result

```
objShell.sendKeys "set Logfile ""L:\09 Phones\Switch_Logs\"& StrDate &".txt"""
```

Comment: Thanks for this but when I enter it and run it I get.   The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect. Failed to create log file

Comment: @ChrisMartin, the quoting process in vbs is the indicated, BUT, sorry, if the `telnet` you are using is the MS one, you can not include spaces/quotes in the `set logfile` command. But you can use the `-f filename` argument in the `telnet` command.